# Tree map not sorting in order

Tags: dictionary, tree, linked-list

So my code so far reads in lines from a file, stores them in two separate ArrayLists. Now I'm going to have to make each node in a doubly Linked List contain the line's string and the corresponding integer, but since I cant put two ArrayLists in the declaration for a Linked List, I tried making a Tree map where the key is the string and the value is the corresponding integer. Here's the relevant code

```
public class FileReaderProgram
 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String stringComponent = " ";
int integerComponent = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the absolute path of the file");
String fileName = in.next();             //Gets the file from the user
File inFile = new File(fileName);
**Map<String,Integer> lineCombo = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();**

try
{
   Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inFile); //Constructs Scanner for reading the file
   fileReader.useDelimiter("\\n");
   while (fileReader.hasNextLine())
   {
     String line = fileReader.nextLine();                  //Gets line from the file
     Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);    //Constructs new scanner to analyize the line

     lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");     

     stringComponent = lineScanner.next();     //Read first word
     while (!lineScanner.hasNextInt())
     {
       stringComponent = stringComponent + " " + lineScanner.next();  //Checks if more than one word part of string
     }
     integerComponent = lineScanner.nextInt(); //Read in integer


     words.add(stringComponent);    //Array of Strings, element number corresponding to the line it came from
     numbers.add(integerComponent);  //Array of Ints, same thing as above

     **lineCombo.put(stringComponent, integerComponent);**


   }
}
```

So when I run the file:

example string,1

another example,42

data,200

final,150

it prints out {another example=42, data=200, example string=1, final=150}
Why is it putting the strings in the wrong order?

Comment: A `TreeMap` is sorted by its keys - which are the strings. Looks pretty much like the expected behaviour to me.

Comment: NVM I figured it out! I used a LinkedHashMap